# Relation "metadata" in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, metadata, relationship

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology here, but this is what I want to do:

On a relation between two types, I want to add metadata about that relationship.
In SQL you can for example have a connection table that holds a bit of extra data about the relationship.

For example if we have two types:

```
type Todo {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    lists: [List]
}

type List {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    todos: [Todo]
}
```

And then on the "relationship" between a `Todo` and a `List` I want to have `order` as metadata, which describes which order a `Todo` has on a give `List`.

(Perhaps not the best example, but hopefully, you get the idea).

Any points on how to accomplish this in GraphQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to utilize a third type to represent the relationship between the other two types.

```
type Todo {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  lists: [ListTodo]
}

type ListTodo {
  list: List
  todo: ToDo
  order: Int
}

type List {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  todos: [ListTodo]
}
```

If you utilize the [connection pattern](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm), the data from the join table can be added to the appropriate edge type:

```
type Todo {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  lists: ListConnection
}

type ListConnection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo
  edges: [ListEdge]
}

type ListEdge {
  cursor: String
  node: Edge
  order: Int
}
```

Comment: That helped alot! Thanks!
For anyone else interested in learning more about the connection pattern I found this article useful:
https://www.apollographql.com/blog/explaining-graphql-connections-c48b7c3d6976

Comment: Here's [the official spec](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm).